# RMI Configuration in JBoss 7

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x, rmi

Our current application is configured using RMI protocol. Now we are migrating the same on JBoss7.2 and JDK 1.7 versons. Since JBoss 7 has removed the support of RMI, could any one help on this a how can we configure RMI in JBoss 7?

Below one is code snippet -

Service configuration -

```
<bean id="claimsOSRMIRegistry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
    <property name="port" value="${rmi.port}" />
</bean>

<!-- Exposing RMI services starts -->
<bean id="reportedClaimService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="${context.root}ReportedClaimService"/>
    <property name="service">
        <ref bean="reportedClaimServiceProxy" />
    </property>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.claimsos.claim.ReportedClaimService"/>
    <property name="registry">
        <ref bean="claimsOSRMIRegistry"/>
    </property>
    <property name="registerTraceInterceptor" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Client Configuration -

```
<bean id="reportedClaimService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl"
value="${rmi.service.location}ReportedClaimService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"
value="com.claimsos.claim.ReportedClaimService" />
    <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Here is my RMI port configuration -

```
rmi.port=1199
rmi.service.location=rmi://localhost:${rmi.port}/${context.root}
```

If any one has any suggestion or have come a crossed this, Please do share.